# When changing language in symfony2 using JMSI18nRoutingBundle parameter issue occure

Tags: php, symfony

app/config/config.yml

```
jms_i18n_routing: 
    default_locale: en locales: [de,en,es,it,tr,fr,zh,ru,da] 
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

This route is define in my routing.yml

```
app_layers:
    pattern:  /app-headers/design/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: DesignAppBundle:App:design, id: 1}
```

I am accessing this page using this link
http://mydomain/app-headers/design/1

but when I change the parameter like

http://mydomain/app-headers/design/2
It works, but when changing any language it is again redirecting to parameter 1

For example: When i change my language from English to Chinese

before change: http://mydomain/app-headers/design/2
After change language : http://mydomain/zh/app-headers/design/1

but it should be like:  http://mydomain/zh/app-headers/design/2

Comment: Please can you put code of langauge.

Comment: app/config/config.yml

jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [de,en,es,it,tr,fr,zh,ru,da]
    strategy: prefix_except_default